# Fill a GridLayout from Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, grid, grid-layout

I'm android studio noob. I'm trying to fill a grid layout from kotlin activity.

My code for the xml is this:

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:rowCount="3"
    app:columnCount="2">

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

In the MainActivity there is a `for` to create every buttom like this:

```
val gridLayout: GridLayout = findViewById(R.id.grid)

for (i in 1..10){
   val button = Button(this)
   button.text = "Boton: " + i

   // GridLayout.add(Buttom)
        
}
```

Who can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't work. It says "Grid keeps stopping". But thanks for your message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify Your Function as Per the given Code.

```
     for (i in 1..10){
        val button = Button(this)
        button.text = "Boton: " + i
        val param = GridLayout.LayoutParams(
            GridLayout.spec(
                GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f
            ),
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL, 1f)
        )

        button.layoutParams = param
        gridLayout.addView(button)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I should change `import android.widget.GridLayout` to `import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;`

And use `gridLayout.addView(button)` to add the button